# JHipster JWT update on logon

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I created gateway customizing the logon procedure (specifying a custom DB to read the user's datas).
When DAOAuthenticationProvider do:

```
UserDetails loadedUser =this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
```

I see an UPDATE starting over the logon table. But no-one do a persist or a save.
It's strange! It tries to save when I try to load.
Debugging into the system I see a transaction starts when loadUserByUsername is called...but it's only a LOAD!!!
Why this appens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The reason was I change a value of object User during logon (before the find).
Removing this change all goes well.